# Android - how can I use FloatingLabel in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have old project that uses [Floating Label](https://github.com/hardik-trivedi/FloatingLabel) , when I try import this old project to android studio I face some problem

one of them importing Floating label library

[image]

**Update Question**

as answer I got , I should use [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html)

here is sample code from my floating label

```
 <com.hardik.floatinglabel.FloatingLabelView
            android:id="@+id/mob"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:padding="5dp"
            floatview:floatHintText="@string/mob"
            floatview:floatHintTextColorFocused="@color/blue"
            floatview:floatHintTextColorUnFocused="@color/green"
            floatview:floatHintTextStyle="bold"
            floatview:textBackground="@drawable/edt_bg" />
```

how can I approach the same result in `TextInputLayout`

Comment: Are you importing an Eclipse project to Android Studio?

Comment: yes , but in my way , manual import as project structure is different

Comment: Floating labels for editing text are now available officially with **Android Design library**. Maybe you can drop the library: http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: thank you for your answer , but I update my question , I need approach same result I got in floating label with TextInputLayout

Comment: @minafawzy iOS and Android have different design guidelines. You should not be using the exact same design.

Answer (score 1):

Android floating labels were introduced in android design support library to display a floating label over EditText.

xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```